# How can I tell RestTemplate to POST with UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: json, spring, resttemplate

I'm having problems posting JSON with UTF-8 encoding using RestTemplate. Default encoding for JSON is UTF-8 so the media type shouldn't even contain the charset. I have tried to put charset in the MediaType but it doesn't seem to work anyway.

My code:

```
String dataJson = "{\"food\": \"smörrebröd\"}";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application", "json", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
headers.setContentType(mediaType);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(dataJson, headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<Boolean> formEntity = restTemplate.exchange(postUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Boolean.class);
```

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You need to add StringHttpMessageConverter to rest template's message converter with charset UTF-8. Like this

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
        .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I had an issue with a special character which look's like '(single quotes). Had a nightmare in parsing it. Simple tweak worth a 1000 votes

Comment: @mushfek0001 it didn't help i changed as mentioned below. I was able to change charset

Comment: How can I switch between charset 8 and 16

Comment: Why `.add(0, ...` and not just `.add(new StringHttp...`?

Comment: @mushfek0001 Update Charset.forName("UTF-8") to StandardCharsets.UTF_8

Comment: You should use StandardCharsets.UTF_8 here rather than a String representation i.e. .getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Comment: simple and easy to use

Comment: why this isn't default? It took me half an hour to check char by char to notice bad encoding :(

Comment: For me the `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` also works in most cases when returning Strings. But I had a problem today when my ResponseEntity returned an png-image in the body. This could only be displayed when I set it to the (default) `StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`. And there was no error, just the image _could not be displayed_

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! I was stuck since 2 days. This helped +1

Answer (score 33):

*(Adding to solutions by mushfek0001 and zhouji)*

By default RestTemplate has **ISO-8859-1** StringHttpMessageConverter which is used to convert a JAVA object to request payload.

Difference between UTF-8 and ISO-8859:

> UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding that can represent any Unicode
> character. ISO 8859-1 is a single-byte encoding that can represent the
> first 256 Unicode characters. Both encode ASCII exactly the same way.

#### Solution 1 (copied from mushfek001):

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
        .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

#### Solution 2:

Though above solution works, but as zhouji pointed out, it will add two string converters and it may lead to some regression issues.

If you set the right content type in http header, then ISO 8859 will take care of changing the UTF characters.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
```

or

```
// HttpUriRequest request
request.addHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
```

Comment: Solution 2 is not an option for non-standard content types, like the one used for bulk operation in ElasticSearch REST API (application/x-ndjson).

Comment: solution 1 works, but solution 2 `headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);` not work, sprint boot version 2.1.2, jdk 1.8

Comment: Solution 2 is working simply with headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8); It is simple and elegant solution. Nice explanation too.

Comment: MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE is deprecated now

Comment: can we do the same with @Autowired RestTemplate?

Comment: @USM Yes you can, but you should update it in the Spring configuration where it is defined, rather than modifying it in your application code while processing a request.

Comment: solution  2 is best solution.

Answer (score 10):

The answer by @mushfek0001 produce two `StringHttpMessageConverter` which will send two `text/plain` and `*/*`, such as the debug picture.

[image]

Even the `Accept` header of client will be:

```
text/plain, text/plain, */*, */*
```

So the better one is **remove** the ISO-8859-1 `StringHttpMessageConverter` and use single UTF-8 `StringHttpMessageConverter`.

Use this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
stringHttpMessageConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(true);
for (int i = 0; i < restTemplate.getMessageConverters().size(); i++) {
    if (restTemplate.getMessageConverters().get(i) instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter) {
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().remove(i);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(i, stringHttpMessageConverter);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't observe such problem. In my case the Accept header had value `application/json, application/*+json` which is OK.

Comment: can we do the same with @Autowired RestTemplate?

Answer (score 3):

Adding new StringHttpMessageConverter won't help. 
In existing StringHttpMessageConverter we need to set writeAcceptCharset to false
and build httpheader with charset we want.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
   List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> c = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
        for(HttpMessageConverter<?> mc :c){
            if (mc instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter) {
                StringHttpMessageConverter mcc = (StringHttpMessageConverter) mc;
                mcc.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
            }
   }

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
  headers.setAcceptCharset(Arrays.asList(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
  HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonPayload, headers);

  restTemplate.postForEntity(postResourceUrl, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Adding new StringHttpMessageConverter helped.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the existing converter, but with Java 8 (why do people still write Java 7 Code anyways?)

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
converters.removeIf(httpMessageConverter -> httpMessageConverter instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter);
converters.add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));

String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
```

Comment: Can you provide some context to your answer, that way future readers can learn how to apply it to their issues and not just in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Better you should remove the StringHttpMessageConverter first before adding new. so this way you will have one instance of StringHttpMessageConverter in our MessageConverters list.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final Iterator<HttpMessageConverter<?>> iterator = restTemplate.getMessageConverters().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final HttpMessageConverter<?> converter = iterator.next();
            if (converter instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }


        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().set(1,new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charsets.UTF_8));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring Boot it will auto-configure RestTemplate with a high-priority UTF-8 charset StringHttpMessageConverter, if you use [RestTemplateBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html) to create the RestTemplate instance. E.g. `restTemplateBuilder.build()`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
HttpHeaders attachmentHeader = new HttpHeaders();
attachmentHeader.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("text/csv; charset=UTF-8"));
```

Or

```
 attachmentHeader.set("Content-Type", "text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
```