# Spring webclient add httpmessageconverter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, resttemplate, spring-webclient

I want to convert spring resttemplate to spring webclient.
in spring resttemplate we can add message converters

[How can I tell RestTemplate to POST with UTF-8 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392422/how-can-i-tell-resttemplate-to-post-with-utf-8-encoding)

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

How can I do it in spring webclient? I want to add message converter to webclient

Answer (score 0):

In WebClient you can setup custom codecs(Encoder, Decoder, HttpMessageReader, HttpMessageWriter) using `WebClient.builder().codecs()`

Here is an example:

```
WebClient.builder()
   .codecs(
        clientCodecConfigurer ->{
            // .defaultCodecs() set defaultCodecs for you
            // clientCodecConfigurer.defaultCodecs();

            //  You can customize an encoder based on the defualt config.
            //  clientCodecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2Encoder(...)

            // Or 
            // use customCodecs to register Codecs from scratch.
            clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().register(new Jackson2JsonDecoder());
            clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().register(new Jackson2JsonEncoder());
        }

).build();
```